# I need to select where Condition this

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables in MySQL.

1.Table - Answer have attribute and value

```
    Id_Answer      Id_Form      Result                       Total      Average
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      13              1  ["2","3","1","3","1","1","2","3"]     16         2.00
      15              1  ["2","2","1","3","0","2","1","0"]     11         1.38
```

2.Table - Criterion have attribute and value

```
       Id_Criterion .    Id_Form .   Topic           Min .    Max .    Detail
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           1                1       Good person       1.5     2         You is a Good person               
           2                1       Bad person         0     1.4         You is a bad
```

I need to get Critetion.Topic, Critetion.Mix, Critetion.Min, Critetion.Max, Critetion.Detail

By I will use Answer.Average to compare In Criterion.Min and Criterion.Max and Answer.Id_Form = Criterion.Id_Form

How I can create query for this?

Comment: Hi. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Query.

```
select b.Topic, b.Min, b.Max, b.Detail
from Answer a
inner join Criterion b 
on a.Id_Form = b.Id_Form and a.Average between b.Min and b.Max
```

Comment: Apply it to CodeIgniter also